# Remotely log out of another computer client login account

Tags: visual-studio-code

I logged into my github account on different clients to sync, but there was one computer that was out of my control. I can't log out my account. Is there any way for me to log out my vscode account on this computer?

I searched for this question and found no results. I remember that vscode has a client login management feature, but can't remember where

Comment: ??? Are you asking about a github account or a vscode account, and what is a vscode account?  And why is this a problem?  Can't you just close VSCode?

Comment: @TimRoberts vscode can log in to the github account for synchronization operation, which led to my synchronization content sometimes confusing. I think it may be that I logged into the github account of vscode for synchronization in my previous company's computer, but I did not log out when I left.